# To argue that a point is not an accumulation point of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I want to show that $\mathbb Z^2$ has no accumulation points in $\mathbb R^2\backslash\mathbb Z^2$. Is this argument correct? In particular, have I correctly invoked the density property of $\mathbb R$?

> For all $v\in\mathbb R^2\backslash\mathbb Z^2$, there is some
>   $\epsilon >0$ (since $\mathbb R ^+$  is dense in itself) such
>   that the (punctured) $\epsilon$-ball about $v$ does not intersect
>   $\mathbb Z^2$.
>
> (In other words: Because $\mathbb R^+$ is dense in itself, every
>   point in $\mathbb R^2\backslash\mathbb Z^2$ has some 
>   neighbourhood containing no point of $\mathbb Z^2$.)

Comment: @ronno Thanks, I have edited my argument accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you want to invoke a density argument. What you want to show is, given a point $p=(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 - \mathbb Z^2$, that $p$ is not an accumulation point of $\mathbb Z^2$. So, you need to demonstrate that some $\epsilon >0$ exists such that $B_\epsilon(p)$ does not intersect $\mathbb Z^2$. Now, the points of $\mathbb Z^2$ define a grid in $\mathbb R^2$ and the point $p$ is inside some square determined by this grid. Let $\epsilon$ be the smallest of the distance from $p$ to each of the four corners of that square and now you can prove that this $\epsilon $ works. (You might want to draw some pictures if the argument is not clear.)

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I don't need to, but I thought it was easier than specifying an $\epsilon$ (as you have done above).  I am trying to argue that there is always a specific positive number (to choose as $\epsilon$) within $\mathbb R^+$ (to choose $\epsilon$ from)   **due to** the density of $\mathbb R^+$ in itself. Hmm but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: no, I don't see how that follows by a density argument. The proof has to rely on the particular geometry of the sets in question. Notice that the argument I give is geometric and relies on some important property of Euclidean distance.

Comment: Is this argument correct? In particular, does it make sense to talk about the shortest distance from a point to a set?? Thanks again:  "Let $v\in\mathbb R^2\backslash\mathbb Z^2$ and $\epsilon$ be the shortest distance from $v$ to $\mathbb Z^2$. Then..(as above, but without the density argument).."

Comment: yes, this is essentially the argument I gave.

Comment: Yes yes, I was just unsure about my verbal statement of it. I have decided to be safe and just write $\epsilon=\min\{d(v,u): u\in \mathbb Z^2\}$. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument does not work. Meaning, the first line is what you want to prove, but you haven't proven it. (in general since being dense in itself is a trivial property that every space has, it will never be useful).

Also note that just because there is a point from $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the neighborhood doesn't mean that there $\textit{isn't}$ a point from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the neighborhood as well (which is what you want to show). Finally it is worthwhile to note that you don't actually use anything about $\mathbb{Z}^2$ this is a dead giveaway that you are not finished. I mean think about it. If you are trying to show $A$ has no accumulation points in $B\setminus A$ and you don't use anything about $A$ then it is true for any $A$, (this is a point many students miss when first starting out, ie that their theorem is true for everything that has the properties they use in the proof NOT just what they state the theorem for.)

Give $p=(a, b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Z}^2$ we know that $a, b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ so the idea is to choose $\epsilon$ so that $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ as well, and similarly for $b$.

Comment: Yes I understand now, thank you!